# Modular addition and piling up Lemma

Tags: probability

All operations below are in $\mathbb{F}_2$

**Notation**

- $a[i]$: $i^{th}$ bit of $a$
- $\oplus$: bitwise XOR operation
- $+$: Modular addition of bits

**Claim** The modular addition operation $s=a+b$ Can be expressed as $s[i]=a[i]\oplus b[i]\oplus c[i]$. Where $c[i]$ is the carry and and $c[0] = 0$.

**Lemma** For the modular addition operation $s=a+b$, the approximation $s[i]=a[i]\oplus b[i]\oplus a[i-1]$ holds with probability $3/4$. (That means $\Pr[c[i]=a[i-1]]=3/4$).

**Piling up Lemma** Let $X$ And $Y$ Two independent random variables then $\Pr[X\oplus Y=0]=\Pr[X=0]\Pr[Y=0]+(1-\Pr[X=0])(1-\Pr[Y=0])$

Let $A+B=C$ And imagine $D[i]\oplus A[i]\oplus B[i]\oplus Carry[i]=0$ ($Carry[i]$ is the carry of $A[i]+B[i]$) holds with probability $3/4$. Using the Piling Up lemma show that $D[i]\oplus A[i]\oplus B[i]\oplus A[i-1]=0$ Happens with probability of $5/8$

I tried several things without success. Could you give me some advice please to solve this problem. For example I tried :
From $D[i]\oplus A[i]\oplus B[i]\oplus Carry[i]=0$ I can get $(D[i]\oplus A[i]\oplus B[i]\oplus A[i-1])\oplus (Carry[i]\oplus A[i-1])=0$ w.p. $3/4$. Applying Piling up Lemma and doing $p_1=\Pr[(D[i]\oplus A[i]\oplus B[i]\oplus A[i-1]=0)$ and $p_2=\Pr[(Carry[i]\oplus A[i-1])=0]=3/4$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
        3/4&=\Pr[(D[i]\oplus A[i]\oplus B[i]\oplus A[i-1])\oplus (Carry[i]\oplus A[i-1])=0]\\
        &=p_1p_2+(1-p_1)(1-p_2) = p_1 = 1\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}